# Build flutter app with different flutter modules

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios, flutter-android, flutter-module

I have my native application, which we want to change into flutter. For that, we have decided to build multiple flutter modules and add that to the existing native application. I am not sure whether flutter support building multiple modules in a single native application.
Also in the future, as we want to move away from native completely, I didn't find any solution where we can build a fresh flutter application using already developed flutter modules.

Comment: you can use flutter with your native android.https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app/android/project-setup

Comment: Yeh..I did that for one module..but the query I have is around multiple modules and cross interaction beween different modules and how to build a fresh flutter app with various flutter modules.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible. What you can do is create modules (packages) somewhere in your project, for example, create a directory `modules` and place them there.

```
.
├── modules
│   ├── module1
│   ├── module2
│   ├── module3
│   └── module4
```

To add them to the current project, in your `pubspec.yaml`, you can do the following:

```yaml
dependencies:
    # ...
    module1:
        path: ./modules/module1
    # ... etc for other modules
```

These local modules are called [path dependencies](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#path-packages).